# How to extract data from a column in excel row for row? (Python - Selenium/xlrd/Pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, selenium

I am trying to extract data from a column in an excel file and I want to be able to take the data from each row and input it into a field on my companies website.
My excel spreadsheet looks something like this..

```
[Column A] [Column B]
   Zach       1111
   Chris      2222
   Jake       3333
```

With the code I currently have, it will take the data from the columns and store them in names and codes. My issue is that when it starts to input the information in the website, it still uses the information from the last cell in the range. For example, the first loop will input Zach 1111 but then the second loop it will input ZachChris 11112222 when I only need it to input Chris 2222 and so forth. How do I go about fixing this so it will input the information row for row instead of keeping all the previous rows?

Here is my code, I've left out information that does not apply to the problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()


def addCodes():
    global driver
    path = 'test.xlsx' 
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
    sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
    names = []
    codes = []
    for y in range(sheet.nrows):
        names.append(str(sheet.cell_value(y, 0)))
        codes.append(str(sheet.cell_value(y, 1)))
        print(names)
        print(codes)
        codeadd = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/main/div/form/div[2]/div[5]/p/input')
        nameadd = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/main/div/form/div[2]/div[6]/p/input')
        codeadd.clear()
        nameadd.clear()
        codeadd.send_keys(codes) 
        nameadd.send_keys(names)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/main/div/form/div[2]/input').send_keys(Keys.SHIFT,Keys.ENTER)
        .... more unnecessary code...
```

Comment: is codeadd.clear() clearing the content?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you **append** the values to the lists `names` and `codes` in each row. If you pass that list containing all the previous entries to the selenium `send_keys` method, the elements are joined and you get the observed behaviour. If you want to keep all values in the lists `names` and `codes` for other purposes, you can simply call the `send_key` method with the corresponding index to send only one element:

```
    codeadd.send_keys(codes[y]) 
    nameadd.send_keys(names[y])
```